# Iterate in terraform provider for kubernetes

Tags: terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

Looking to get workaround for adding loop in provider resource? for example, count. I am getting this:
The provider argument name "count" is reserved for use by Terraform in a future version.

My use case is, i want to create multiple clusters using terraform gke cluster module. Now i am able to do that.
Next step is to create kubernetes_storage_class say xfs on each cluster which can be done in terraform via

```
resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "xfs"
```

which requires kubernetes provider as :

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = "https://${module.gke_cluster.host}"
  token                  = module.gke_cluster.token
  cluster_ca_certificate = module.gke_cluster.cluster_ca_cert
}
```

This part is failing. Error with above setting is:

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on cluster.tf line 18, in provider "kubernetes":
│   18:   host                   = "https://${module.client_cluster.host}"
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.client_cluster is a list of object, known only after apply
│
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access attribute "host" for a specific element of the list, or across all elements of the list?
```

When trying with this setting:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = "https://${module.client_cluster[0].host}"
  token                  = module.client_cluster[0].token
  cluster_ca_certificate = module.client_cluster[0].cluster_ca_cert
}
```

Its working fine but this will have endpoint only of 1st cluster ( say i wanted to create 3 cluster)

Now i tried adding count in provider so it can get endpoint of each created cluster:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  count                  = 3
  host                   = "https://${module.client_cluster[count.index].host}"
  token                  = module.client_cluster[count.index].token
  cluster_ca_certificate = module.client_cluster[count.index].cluster_ca_cert
}
```

This one fails as:
The provider argument name "count" is reserved for use by Terraform in a future version.

If anyone has any experience or any workaround, please let me know. Else i have a crude way of doing this as  copying pasting as many module block as many clusters we need.

Comment: The Kubernetes provider configuration corresponds to the specific cluster, and so you will need multiple provider blocks (one per each cluster managed by your module). This is also because you cannot use meta-arguments with enumerable values in a single provider block as indicated by the thrown error message.

Comment: But it means i need to create as many blocks of provider which i won't know before. I am looking into for_each within provider block and will see how it goes.

Comment: After version 2.3.2 of the Kubernetes provider it was no longer possible to initially manage the backing infra for the clusters, and the clusters themselves with a single `apply`, so there is no drawback to the unknowns here anymore.

Answer (score 2):

What you try to do is not possible in Terraform for the mentioned shotcomings and limitations.

You could use [Terramate](https://github.com/mineiros-io/terramate) to generate the code dynamically before running normal Terraform commands.

```
// cluster.tm.hcl - terramate config file

stack { # define the current directory as a stack
  id = "my-unique-stack-id"
}

generate_hcl "cluster.tf" { # generate Terraform code

  lets {
    clusters = [
      { id = "cluster1", config = {} },
      { id = "cluster2", config = {} },
      { id = "cluster3", config = {} },
    ]
  }

  content {
    locals {
      clusters = let.clusters
    }

    module "client_cluster" {
      for_each = { for c in local.clusters : c.id => c } # create the 3 clusters by id

      source = "...."            # source of the module used

      # your inputs go here e.g.
      name = each.value.id
    }

    # create 3 provider blocks and use id as alias
    tm_dynamic "provider" {
      for_each = let.clusters

      labels = ["kubernetes"]

      content {
        alias                  = provider.value.id
        host                   = "https://${module.client_cluster[provider.value.id].host}"
        token                  = module.client_cluster[provider.value.id].token
        cluster_ca_certificate = module.client_cluster[provider.value.id].cluster_ca_cert
      }
    }

    tm_dynamic "resource" {
      for_each = let.clusters

      labels = ["kubernetes_storage_class", "xfs"]

      content {
        provider = tm_hcl_expression("kubernetes.${resource.value.id}")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Running `terramate generate` will generate the following `cluster.tf` file:

```
// TERRAMATE: GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY DO NOT EDIT

locals {
  clusters = [
    {
      config = {}
      id     = "cluster1"
    },
    {
      config = {}
      id     = "cluster2"
    },
    {
      config = {}
      id     = "cluster3"
    },
  ]
}
module "client_cluster" {
  for_each = { for c in local.clusters : c.id => c } # create the 3 clusters by id
  name     = each.value.id
  source   = "...."
}
provider "kubernetes" {
  alias                  = "cluster1"
  cluster_ca_certificate = module.client_cluster["cluster1"].cluster_ca_cert
  host                   = "https://${module.client_cluster["cluster1"].host}"
  token                  = module.client_cluster["cluster1"].token
}
provider "kubernetes" {
  alias                  = "cluster2"
  cluster_ca_certificate = module.client_cluster["cluster2"].cluster_ca_cert
  host                   = "https://${module.client_cluster["cluster2"].host}"
  token                  = module.client_cluster["cluster2"].token
}
provider "kubernetes" {
  alias                  = "cluster3"
  cluster_ca_certificate = module.client_cluster["cluster3"].cluster_ca_cert
  host                   = "https://${module.client_cluster["cluster3"].host}"
  token                  = module.client_cluster["cluster3"].token
}
resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "xfs" {
  provider = kubernetes.cluster1
}
resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "xfs" {
  provider = kubernetes.cluster2
}
resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "xfs" {
  provider = kubernetes.cluster3
}
```

You will need to use [alias configs for providers](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/providers/configuration#selecting-alternate-provider-configurations) so that you can address the cluster you want to deploy a `kubernetes_` resource to.

In addition your `count` was converted to a `for_each` to make the results more readable and allow to provide different configs.

Terramate helps to generate code for such complex scenarios to circumvent shortcomings in Terraform and scales to any number of clusters in this case.

Terramate also allows to drop in any pure terraform code so you can just generate parts of your stack.

The code is just meant as an example, I did not test the resulting generated code due to missing details.